# javascript little algorithm to calculate prices

Tags: javascript

I am developing a little website and I have 20 product selling.

Each week I want to calculate new prices for every product taking into account the number of sells done of each product but following two rules:

- The sum of the 20 products' prices must always be 100€
- I want every product to be integer (no decimal) or to be .5, I mean, one product's price can be 7 or 8 or 9 or 7.5 or 8.5 but not 8.3 or 7.1.

Lets' make an example but simplifying with 4 products:

Sells this week:

```
product_id  sells
----------  ------
     1       45
     2       31
     3       12
     4       62
```

ok, total sells then are 150.

If i divide those 100€ by 150 sells I get 0.667€/sell. So If I multiply every product by this value I am getting:

```
product_id  sells  raw_price_next_week
----------  ------  -------------------
     1       45             30.015
     2       31             20.677
     3       12             8.004
     4       62             41.354
```

Then I need to normalize those raw_prices taking into account the second rule I mentioned before, getting the closest 0.5 multiple of each raw_value...

```
product_id  sells  raw_price_next_week    final_price
----------  ------  -------------------    ------------
     1       45             30.015             30
     2       31             20.677             20.5
     3       12             8.004              8
     4       62             41.354             41.5
```

I've been thinking on how to code this little algo but the fact is that I don't even know how to start. I need some expert help...

Comment: That's a very unusual store you're running. It's almost as though this were a homework problem.

Comment: What have you tried? I have a solution, but I'm not going to post it until I've seen what you've attempted.

Comment: i thought of an array to store sellscount name for example as sellscount. Then add all sells on the array and store it in var totalsells. Then var coef=100/totalsells. Then for each cell in sellscount I multiply it with coef. Here is where i don't know how to adjust the output numbers to 0.5 multiples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you need to actually display the finished results or not but this should provide the correct calculations.

```js
// Start with the raw product data (array of object - from database likely)
    var 
        products = [
            {
                product_id: 1,
                sells: 45
            },
            {
                product_id: 2,
                sells: 31
            },
            {
                product_id: 3,
                sells: 12
            },
            {
                product_id: 4,
                sells: 62
            }
        ]
    ;
    
    // ###############################################################
    
    window.Pricing = {
        
        total_sum: 100, // This represents the 100€
        sales : 0,
        
        init: function( products ) {     
            return this.calculate_final_price( products );
        },
           
        get_price_per_sale: function( products ) {
    
            for( x in products ) {
                this.sales += products[x].sells;        
            }
            
            return this.total_sum / this.sales;                
        },
        
        calculate_final_price: function( products ) {
                    
            var price_per_sale = this.get_price_per_sale( products );
            
            for( x in products ) {
                products[x].raw_price_next_week = +( products[x].sells * price_per_sale );
                products[x].final_price = +( Math.round( products[x].raw_price_next_week * 2 ) / 2 ).toFixed(1);        
            }
            
            return products;
        }
        
    };
    
    // ###############################################################
    
    // Init the pricing calculations and get the final objects with updated pricing.
    Pricing.init( products );
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/0nbbojp9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here's what I came up with in javascript like you asked for. Also you can test it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/justanotherguy/xbev1bm5/).

```
// 1.) Set array for product prices... I just put a random number of products
var productPrices = [10,20,20,30,30,30,25,10];

// 2.) Get initial total price to calculate price change
var productPriceSum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < productPrices.length; i++) {
    productPriceSum += productPrices[i];
}
var priceChange = (100/productPriceSum);

// 3.) Change prices rounding to the nearest .5
productPriceSum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < productPrices.length; i++) {
    var newPrice = Math.round((productPrices[i]*priceChange)*10)/10
    var npDecimal = (newPrice - Math.floor(newPrice))
    if(npDecimal < 0.5){
        newPrice = Math.floor(newPrice)
    }else{
        newPrice = Math.floor(newPrice) + .5
    }
    productPrices[i] = newPrice;
    productPriceSum += newPrice;
}

// 4.) Account for any missing or excess of numbers to get the total back to 100
var makeEvenHundred = (100 - productPriceSum)
for(var i = 0; i < (makeEvenHundred*2); i ++){
    if(makeEvenHundred < 0){
        productPrices[i] -= .5
    }else{
        productPrices[i] += .5
    }
}

// Proof it all worked!
productPriceSum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < productPrices.length; i++) {
    alert('Product # ' + (i+1) + ' Price: ' + productPrices[i]);
    productPriceSum += productPrices[i];
}
alert('Total: ' + productPriceSum);
```

Also note that section #4 will probably need to be tweaked however you want the logic to work there. The way I threw it together, it will add or remove the values to the first prices until the total has gotten back to 100. Also it assumes that there will in fact be enough products to add or remove .5 at a time (You said 20, so I assume this would work).

So if this website is any success, just know I did all the work for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The trick is to break the problem into small pieces and deal with each one separately. Here's the breakdown:

1. Round the value down to the nearest integer.
2. Capture the decimal value.
3. Divide the decimal value to see how many '0.5's make up this value.
4. Multiple the number of 0.5's to get the closest 0.5 value.
5. Sum the value from 1. with the value from 4.

You can adjust the `closest` variable to round to different values as well.

Below is the implementation of this. You can use the `map` function to execute the `normalization` on all values in the data array. In your case, it would be the result of some ajax call.

### Implementation

```js
var data = [30.015, 20.677, 8.004, 41.354];

function normalize(value) {
  var closest = 0.5;
  var significand = Math.floor(value);
  var mantissa = (value % 1).toFixed(2);
  var normalized = Math.round(mantissa / closest) * closest;
  return significand + normalized;
}

var normalized = data.map(normalize);

console.log(normalized);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

### Resources

- [Array Map Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)